# Python regular expression for capturing extended row in a table

Tags: regex

## Table 1:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     Po50(SU)     Eth      ACP      inth1/13(P)   inet1/14(P)  
12    Po10(RU)    Eth      ACP      inth1/1/1(P)  inet1/1/2(H)  inet1/1/3(P)
                                                         inet1/1/4(H) 
23    Po52(SU)    Eth      ACP      inth1/2(P)   
30    Po53(SU)    Eth      ACP      inth1/3(P)   
50    Po55(SU)    Eth      ACP      inth1/6(P) 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the row 12 from the above table which is extended to the next line as in the below

```
12    Po10(RU)    Eth      ACP      inth1/1/1(P)  inet1/1/2(H)  **inet1/1/3(P)**
                                                         inet1/1/4(H)
```

I tried the below

re.findall(r"(\d{1,4}?) +(.+?) +(\w+?) +(\w+) +(.+?) +(.+?) +(.+?) +(.+)", i, re.MULTILINE)

however its getting truncated at the last string - "**inet1/1/3(P)**" and am not able to get the string "**inet1/1/4(H)**"

Any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture? And why does your regex have so many capturing groups?

Comment: I want to open and read the above Table 1 as  a text file and match the extended row 12 and convert that to a dictionary - {Po10(RU) : [inet1/1/2(H), inet1/1/4(H)] }. Here I am able to get the dictionary as {Po10(RU) : inet1/1/2(H) } and the value -  inet1/1/4(H) is ignored in my regex.

Comment: It is working as expected https://regex101.com/r/HsU94q/1

Comment: @ThamaraiSelvam, your table is a file or a pure string?

Comment: Can you read in the file as a  single string? If yes, then you may use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/vsxBw3/2). Maybe named groups will make it more usable.

Comment: My Table is a text file - "show_cli.txt"